# Did Cameron betray John Connor?

Tags: character, terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In the final episode *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* season 2, when Cameron meets John Henry, he is asking Cameron **"Will you join us?"**  After that John Connor finds Cameron's body but her chip and John Henry are missing. In the display screens a message is showing for John Connor that says **"I'm sorry John"**.

So why did Cameron give her chip to John Henry. The chip had all the information about John Connor. Did John Henry travel to the future with Cameron's chip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, she didn't since Catherine Weaver's goal is to stop Skynet and John Henry is her way in doing so. So helping John Henry was the right/logical thing to do.

As for "I'm sorry", it was meant to be as "I'm sorry for leaving/giving away my chip and getting deactivated".